# returning a array doesnt act like a array

Tags: php, arrays, return

I am wondering why this doesnt work.

As of at least PHP 5.3, a function or class method returning an object acts like an object.

```
<?php

class A {
function test() {
    echo "Yay!";
    }
}

function get_obj() {
    return new A();
}


function get_array() {
    return array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
}

get_obj()->test();  // "works
echo get_array()[1]; // and this fails 
?>
```

I found this at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

would someone clarify why it doesn't work for arrays but works for objects.

EDIT:

added get_array()

Comment: do you know that you haven't posted the `get_array()` code?

Comment: I forgot to add it i will add it now

Answer (score 3):

function array dereferencing was [added](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) in PHP 5.4, so unless you're on 5.4+, you have to do

```
$temp = get_array();
echo $temp[0];
```

Comment: thanks this is what i was looking for i did not know this (i am running 5.3.13 so that was my problem good to know that this has been implemented)

Answer (score 0):

Is `get_array()` defined somewhere? If so, paste that code.

Comment: Is it a answer for this question?

Comment: I believe what you are referring is array dereferencing.. and has been activated in php 5.4 and up. http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html

Comment: No, I was wondering if the code even has a function called `get_array()`

Comment: It was just a piece of code for explanation, But I forgot to add get_array(). It has been added.